# Run several ssh in a row (one within another)

Tags: ssh, sudo, sudosh

I would like to do the following in a one-liner (so I can alias it in my `.bashrc`)

```
0. before doing anything I am user1 on server0 
1. ssh to server1
2. impersonate user2 (**THIS HAS TO BE DONE BY `sudo -u user2 sudosh`**)
3. ssh from server1 to server2
4. cd dirOnServer2
```

so my prompt would be after

```
user@server0:/dirOnServer0) superSshCommand
user2@server2:/dirOnServer2)
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: `ssh server1 "sudo -l user2 ssh server2"  `

Comment: This is not working, you would need at least `ssh -t -q` and I cannot `sudo` I need `tty` (sudo -u user2 sudosh)

Comment: Why not `ssh user2@server1.example.com 'ssh server2.example.com'`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti impersonate user2 take a command...

Comment: @statquant now that you've edited your question to state that `sudosh` is mandatory, you cannot solve this problem because `sudosh` doesn't allow chaining of commands via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this can be achieved in a single command, and therefore can be put into an alias:

```
ssh -t server1 sudo -u user2 ssh server2
```

However, changing directory is harder. If you can guarantee that `user2` should always land in your target directory you could put the `cd dirOnServer2` into your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) like this:

```
cd dirOnServer2
```

Be aware that the directory change will only happen if the `.profile` is sourced, and this only happens for an interactive shell.

Comment: Hello, as I wrote `sudo -u user2` is not possible it has to be `sudo -u user2 sudosh` If that's what you meant, well this is not working, it appears that it does not do the last ssh

Comment: @statquant you cannot solve the problem if `sudosh` is involved because it doesn't allow chaining of commands via the command line.